# Excluir linha de um dataset não contida em outro [R]

Tags: r

Olá, estou fazendo um trabalho sobre IDH e Covid e preciso de juntar duas colunas, o problema é que ambas estão com número de linhas diferentes, e o motivo é o número de municípios em que cada uma tem, uma mais atualizada com menos e outra mais antiga com mais.

Em ambas, eu tenho o código de município e creio que com isso eu consiga excluir do dataset de IDH as linhas de municípios que o código não está no dataset de Covid.

Mas não está dando certo, alguém imagina como fazer?

As colunas do dataset de IDH:
nome, idhm_r, code

As colunas do dataset de COVID:
name, code, cases, deaths

Ambas já estão ordenadas pelo código.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Em IDH está `nome` com `o` e no Covid `name` com `a`? Seja como for, `i<-which(IDH$code %in% Covid$code)` seguido de `IDH2 <- IDH[i,]` seleciona as linhas de IDH com códigos em Covid.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação de `?dplyr::anti_join()`. Deve te ajudar.